# How do I get a wrapped ListView like the one in the Android Setup Screen?

Tags: android, listview

I'm trying to achieve something like the wrapped ListView  in the language selector in the Android setup.

I looked through Android Studio but can't seem to find anything like it.

Is there a way to achieve something like this ?

[image: Here's what I mean]

Comment: You can use a [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html)

Comment: *I looked through Android Studio* -- Yeah, that's just the IDE. You won't find much of the Android source code there. Just templates.

Comment: Try NumberPicker - https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/NumberPicker.html

Comment: @Jahnold Yes, that did the trick, thank you! I managed to display Strings as values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CharacterPickerWindow mOptions = new CharacterPickerWindow(activity);
setPickerData(mOptions.getPickerView());
mOptions.setSelectOptions(0, 0, 0);
mOptions.setOnoptionsSelectListener(new CharacterPickerWindow.OnOptionsSelectListener() {
@Override
public void onOptionsSelect(int options1, int option2, int options3) {

}
});
mOptions.showAtLocation(v, Gravity.BOTTOM, 0, 0);
```

> For more see this [Click here](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/2806)

Answer (score 0):

The best approach I've found: https://github.com/Carbs0126/NumberPickerView

It has very reach config (such as inactive item color, active item color, divider color, divider height, etc).

Here's my example of usage:

[image: My example]